# How to return a specific directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code, I am trying to print a selected path. Whenever I print the code, it shows me correct result but when I return this code, it gives me the following error.

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 103, in <module>
    directory = listdirs(rootdir, 2)
  File "main.py", line 99, in listdirs
    return b[dir]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

**Code**

```
import os

subDir = []
def listdirs(path, dir):
    for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for dir in dirs:
            d = os.path.join(roots, dir)
            subDir.append(d)
    b = [s.split(',') for s in subDir]
    return b[dir]
    # print(b[2])

rootdir = '/home/runner/TestP1'
directory = listdirs(rootdir, 2)
print(f"Selected directory: {directory}")
```

Comment: Shouldn't have reused that `dir` name.

Comment: You are trying to access list `b` using str variable `dir` as an index instead of integer value

Comment: Thank you @user2357112supportsMonica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you use the same variable for iterating and as an argument.

```
def listdirs(path, which_dir):
    for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for dir in dirs:
            d = os.path.join(roots, dir)
            subDir.append(d)
    b = [s.split(',') for s in subDir]
    return b[which_dir]

rootdir = '/home/runner/TestP1'
directory = listdirs(rootdir, 2)
print(f"Selected directory: {directory}")
```